# Copying active cell into first empty cell from selected range

Tags: excel, vba

Case is that:
Find first empty cell in declared range. If found then copy value from active cell to "first found empty cell" and exit the loop.

Do not see what should be improved. Probably some errors in exiting from loop.

```
Sub Copie()
Dim myNamedRange As Range
Set myNamedRange = myWorksheet.Range("L2:L11")
For Each cell In myNamedRange
    If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then
        ActiveCell.Value = cell.Value
        Exit For
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't see a question in there.

Comment: @SJR placement of value is wrong way around as Vityata said in his answer.  Also `myWorksheet` not defined.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - I might be picky but I like the OP to spell out a precise question. Yes we can usually work it out, but don't see why we should have to.

Comment: @SJR  That's fair enough and no doubt how it should be.  It's all part of the [MCVE].  Unless the OP explicitly states that the figure keeps appearing in the wrong place we should ask as you did and the _Do not see what should be improved_ statement should really point to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  So, um, yeah... you're right.

Answer (score 1):

To do it without looping you could use `FIND`, but that wouldn't give any visible improvements using a small range.

```
Sub Copy()

    Dim myWorkSheet As Worksheet
    Dim myNamedRange As Range
    Dim FirstEmptyCell As Range

    Set myWorkSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set myNamedRange = myWorkSheet.Range("L2:L11")

    With myNamedRange
        Set FirstEmptyCell = .Find( _
            What:="", _
            After:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            SearchFormat:=False)
    End With

    If Not FirstEmptyCell Is Nothing Then
        FirstEmptyCell = ActiveCell
    Else
        MsgBox "No empty cells found.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `SpecialCells` is another non-looping option.

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveCell.Value = cell.Value` should be `cell.Value = ActiveCell.Value`.

The left part is filled out with the right part. See this small example:

```
Sub TestMe()        
    Dim a As Long
    Dim b As Long
    a = 10
    b = 20
    a = b
    MsgBox a 'shows 20, because it accepted "b"
End Sub
```

Thus, this should work:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim myNamedRange As Range
    Set myNamedRange = Worksheets(1).Range("L2:L11")
    Dim myCell As Range

    For Each myCell In myNamedRange
        If IsEmpty(myCell) Then
            myCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

Comment: @luk.monecki - welcome! You may consider [marking the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)